# Yet another "black screen on boot" issue

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.04, display, screen

*I have read a lot of posts in AskUbuntu about a black screen preventing Ubuntu from booting. Apparently, this is an issue that has persisted for a lot of people across many years and as many posts are left unanswered, I suspect that it is an open bug and nobody has taken the time to dig into it, but I hope my question doesn't end being just "one more", so, against all odds, here I go:*

I have an Asus FX505-DT (Ryzen7, NVIDIA GTX 1650) running Ubuntu 20.04.1 with kernel version 5.4.0-52-generic (though I already had this issue with 19.10) and **sometimes** (it is completely random) when I turn on my computer, a black screen appears after the Ubuntu logo and the system doesn't boot. Here are three behaviours I have noticed:

1. A black screen appears. Keyboard and touchpad are unresponsive (I know because I can't even change the keyboard's backlight with the key combination).
2. A black screen appears **but** the pointer is visible and it is frozen in the bottom-right part of the screen. Still, keyboard and touchpad are unresponsive.
3. A black screen appears and keyboard and touchpad are responsive for a while (i.e. I can move the pointer around the black screen), but then they freeze.

In any of those cases, the only solution is to hard reset the computer (leave the power button pressed until it reboots) and then, most of the times, it happens to boot, but last time I ended up with a corrupted filesystem and... well... I don't want that to happen again. As a side-note, I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed in two different hard-drives and this issue appears after I choose to boot Ubuntu from the GRUB. I have never had any problem with Windows.

I found that many other open questions relate this issue to NVIDIA's drivers, but I have tried with both proprietary and Nouveau's drivers and the issue persists. Also, I have fresh installed Ubuntu 19.10 and Ubuntu 20.04.1 several times (and upgraded) and the issue persists.

I am attaching the `journalctl` logs for the [last black screen boot](https://pastebin.com/zAf6zZPx) and the [last good boot](https://pastebin.com/qBi46SL7) (which happened after hard resetting from the black screen boot) hoping someone who actually understands what's going on can give them a look. I couldn't find anything obvious like "TERRIBLE ERROR HAPPENING HERE!!!" but just the log from the bad boot abruptly ending.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if more information is needed!